# Wigner-Eckart theorem and Van Vleck paramagnetism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, angular-momentum

Using the Wigner-Eckart theorem, we can express the matrix elements of Langevin's paramagnetic Hamiltonian $L_z + g_S S_z$ using only the quantum numbers of the total angular momentum, $J$ and $m_J$, as
$$
\langle n|L_z + g_S S_z|n'\rangle = \hbar g_J \cdot m_J \cdot \delta_{m_J, m_J'}
$$
(see, for instance, *The Quantum Theory of Magnetism* by N. Majlis, p. 9, which is available on Google Boooks).

Obviously, this means that the expectation value of Langevin's term vanishes for a ground state $| n \rangle$ with $J=0$.

On the other hand, however, every textbook on the topic claims that Van Vleck's (smaller) second order paramagnetic contribution to the total energy,

$$
\sum_{n'\neq n} \frac{|\langle n|L_z + g_S S_z |n' \rangle|^2}{E_n - E_{n'}},
$$
does **not** vanish even for $J=0$, as long as $L$ and $S$ are non-zero.

How can this be if I could just apply the same formula as above and find that, again, $m_J = 0$ for $| n \rangle$ and each $| n' \rangle$ and therefore $\langle n|L_z + g_S S_z |n' \rangle = 0$?